# Fetching data from GraphQL server from ReactJs using axios

Tags: reactjs, postgresql, graphql, pg

I followed [this tutorial](https://blog.harveydelaney.com/setting-up-graphql-express-and-postgresql/) to setup my backend. Except that I am returning all users instead of one. So my queries in `queries.js` is something like this.

```
const db = require("../db");
const { GraphQLObjectType, GraphQLID } = require("graphql");
const { UserType } = require("./types");

const RootQuery = new GraphQLObjectType({
    name: "RootQueryType",
    type: "Query",
    fields: {
        user: {
            type: UserType,
            args: {},
            resolve(parentValue, args) {
                const query = `SELECT * FROM users`;
                return db
                  .query(query)   // I use db.query() because I use Pool pg instead of pg-promise
                  .then(res => res.rows)
                  .catch(err => err);
            }
        }
    }
});

exports.query = RootQuery;
```

So from the react js, I tried to fetch it like this.

```
axios
    .get(`/graphql`, {}, headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    })
    .then((res) =>{
        console.log(res)  
    })
```

**Issue 1** : When running my application, it returned an error message `Must provide query string.`.

Do I need a plugin to make it work from the react js side or any body input should be submitted together?

---

**Issue 2** : I have tested a query from the GraphQL GUI but it shows username value as null. Even when I return an array that I write statically from the resolve but it is still showing null.

[image]

**UPDATE :** 
So I tested the submission from postman `"query": "query {user {username}}"` as the body input and it works with single object been returned ( *although my axios still not working* ). The issue here is that my db.query() returns object array.

How should I structure my GraphQL to be able to return object array? Thank you!

Comment: Should be a `POST` not a `GET`